# block visibility snippet restrict path

Tags: blocks

I use the following snippet to restrict who can see a block inside admin pages. Can you help me add the restriction of a path /cart* for non admin users into this snippet?

```
if (user_access('access administration pages')) {
  return FALSE;
} else {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the logic is:

```
Display this block only on pages with a path beginning with cart/*,
And only when the user has `access administration pages` permission
```

If so....

```
if (arg(0)=='cart' && arg(1) && user_access('access administration pages')) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

If you want it displayed on path `cart` all by itself as well, just remove the `&& arg(1)` from the above and then it will work on `cart` in addtion to `cart/foo` and `cart/foo/bar` etc.

If, however, you want it only on `cart/oneargumentonly`, you can add in `&& !arg(2)`.

ADDITION/CORRECTION:

```
if (user_access('access administration pages') || (arg(0)=='cart' && arg(1))) {
  return FALSE;
} else {
  return TRUE;
}
```

while return FALSE if the user can `access administration pages` regardless of the path OR the path is `cart/*` regardless of any permissions.

So, if my logic is right now, if the user can `access administration pages` the `if` is "short circuited" and returns FALSE.  Otherwise, if the user doesn't have this permission, it continues on and if the path is `cart/*` it returns FALSE.  Otherwise, since we already know the user doesn't have the `access administration pages` permission it returns TRUE for any other path.

FINAL?

```
if (user_access('access administration pages') || arg(0)=='cart') {
  return FALSE;
} else {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: No, it should be visible for anybody anywhere except for all paths starting with cart and not visible for admin users at all anywhere.

Comment: ah....ok....brb :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this code. It works ok but I need to hide the block on cart page as well. Now it is hidden for all pages with cart in path. can you tell why this code doesn;t work? `if (user_access('access administration pages')) || (stristr(current_path(),"/cart")
{
  return FALSE;
} 
else {
  return TRUE;
}`

Comment: your code in your comment doesn't work on path `cart` because it (the path) doesn't begin with a `/`, it's just plain old `cart`.  If you take the `&& arg(1)` out of my code it will work on `cart`, `cart/foo`, `cart/foo/bar` etc

Comment: Final solution doe's the trick. Thank you. I need to learn some basics of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is to hide the block in cart/* for non administrator roles.

```
if(stristr(current_path(),"cart/") && user_access('access administration pages')) {
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I was thinking about something like this 
if (user_access('access administration pages')) {
  return FALSE;
} 
elseif (stristr(current_path(),"/cart")
{return false;}
else {
  return TRUE;
}
But it is not working

Comment: Hi,I was thinking about something like this

Comment: almost, this just checks if `cart/` is in the path and thus would match something like `teacart/` anywhere :)